# What Windows 7 services are responsible for automatically increasing free disk space?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, services, windows-services

On a Windows 7 box, the system partition is low on free space.  It typically hovers around 4GB free.

About once a week, I've been told the system partition "magically" increases its free space to about 6-7GB free.

Does Win7 have a cleanup service that runs about once a week?

If so, what is the name of that service, and is there any harm in setting that service to run more frequently?

Are there any other Windows services that would be responsible for automatically resulting in increased free disk space?

Notes: The system has a fixed-size Windows swap file, so that's not resulting  in the fluctuations.  Also, there is no real data stored on the system, and no browser caches.

Answer (score 1):

In a default  Windows 7 configuration the Windows Module Installer Service performs activities that can free up disk space.

After system startup this service is responsible for maintaining the CBS logs generated by Windows Update and other software maintenance activities. It archives the most recent log, compressing it into a CAB file. It will also delete older CAB files to free up disk space. The CBS log can be quite large so this may easily result in noticeable fluctuations in free disk space between system restarts. Well I haven't tested it myself, restarting this service may trigger this cleanup behavior.

The primary tool used in Windows 7 to free up disk space, Disk Cleanup, does not run automatically.

Anecdotally, in my experience Windows workstation installations that experience fluctuations in free disk space usually have at least one third party program installed that is responsible for this behavior. It's quite unusual for a truly default installation of Windows to do anything other than gradually consume more disk space over time.